# android - using a global cache for bitmaps

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I'm developing an android application that deals with bitmaps. Right now I'm using an LRUCache to store these bitmaps, but there are going to be multiple fragments that require access to this cache. What's the best way to handle to handle a global application cache? Should I use a singleton? Should I create a new cache for each activity/fragment that requires access to it?

Comment: Store the Cache in the MainActivity and make a getter like `getBitmapChache()` and call it from your Fragment like `((MainActivity)getActivity()).getBitmapCache()`

Comment: What kind of Bitmaps? You may want to use something like Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) that does this for you.

Comment: Robby, that looks interesting. Do you personally have any experience using it? Positive/negative feedback?

Comment: I use it in several projects and am very happy with it.

Comment: I forgot that I'm storing images on Amazon S3 and am using their API to access the images. I'll probably go with A.S. approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid Singletons in Android Development, like in your question I would suggest anybody using Fragments to store real global Objects in the MainActivity. It should look like this:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    //eg a ArrayList
    private ArrayList<MyObjects> mObjectContainer = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    //Do something with the list and fill it

    public ArrayList<MyObjects> getObjectContainer(){
        return mObjectContainer;
    ]

    public void addObject(MyObject object){
        if(!mObjectContainer.contains(object)){
            mObjectContainer.add(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class MyFirstFragment extends Fragment{

    onCreateView(...){
       //make typical Fragment init like create View 

       ArrayList<MyObjects> list = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getObjectContainer();

       //add a new Object
       ((MainActivity)getActivity).addObject(new MyObject("any data"));
    }
}
```